# why my asp.net project look like references not resolved?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Running VS 2015 RC on windows 7 64, for the asp.net projects, it looks like the screenshot below, there is also no intellisense, but the project can compile, something wrong?

the VS has resharper 9 and web essential extension installed as well

project.json

```
 {
  "webroot": "wwwroot",
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-beta4",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-beta4",
    //"Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta4"
  },

  "commands": {
      "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --server Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener --server.urls http://localhost:5000"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { },
    "dnxcore50": { }
  },

  "publishExclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "**.xproj",
    "**.user",
    "**.vspscc"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "wwwroot",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components"
  ]
}
```

[image]

also, was keep getting the error message
[image]

the activitylog.xml
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They aren't missing, they are just not used. If they were missing/unresolved, there would be a red squiggle. They are dimmed because you aren't using them.

See this: http://csharp.2000things.com/2014/10/28/1213-visual-studio-2014-unused-using-statements-greyed-out/

**Try this for the other issues:**

1. Run VS with /SafeMode switch (eliminates the extension issues and possible conflicts with VS)
2. Uncomment the "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta4" line in the dependencies file

Comment: understanding the grey out, but the red reference is the problem.

Comment: Is this a brand new project from a VS template? Try a rebuild (not a build). Check references. Make sure you have latest VS updates.

Comment: it is, if i hover the red symbols e.g. 'IServiceCollection', it says 'cannot resolve symbol IServiceCollection'

Comment: @TOMMYWANG what do you have listed in your dependencies file? Please update your question with it and let me know if there are any red squiggles in it.

Comment: Let's make sure it isn't your plugins causing an issue. Please run VS with the /SafeMode switch and see if the issues go away

Comment: @TOMMYWANG Also uncomment the "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta4" line

Comment: it works! when i start it in the safe mode. I close it, start normally, get the same issue, so I can't blame visual studio any more, but where is the problem?

Comment: Resharper is the problem